# How do I use c++20 std::is_constant_evaluated in Visual C++ 2019 Community?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std, c++20

MS claim to support is_constant_evaluated on their [conformance page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019)  and their <type_traits> header does include an implementation, guarded with #if _HAS_CXX20.

It seems though that (with MSVC Community 16.6.5, at least) /std:c++latest does not cause _HAS_CXX20 to be defined. The UI does not offer a /std:c++20 option.

e.g.

```
    #include <type_traits>
    static_assert( std::is_constant_evaluated(), "" );
    #ifdef _HAS_CXX20
    static_assert(false, "");
    #endif
```

gives the following output:

```
1>ConsoleApplication7.cpp
1>ConsoleApplication7.cpp(3,21): error C2039: 'is_constant_evaluated': is not a member of 'std'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\type_traits(20): message : see declaration of 'std'
1>ConsoleApplication7.cpp(3,42): error C3861: 'is_constant_evaluated': identifier not found
1>ConsoleApplication7.cpp(5,15): error C2338:
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication7.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Note that the use of is_constant_evauluated produces an error, and that the static_assert does not.

What am I missing?

Comment: "It seems though that (with MSVC Community 16.6.5, at least) /std:c++latest does not cause _HAS_CXX20" -- what do you base this claim off of?  Be concrete.  Did you try a simple program that says `#ifdef _HAS_CXX20 std::cout << "_HAS_CXX20\n" #endif`, for example?

Comment: Fair point, it may be that _HAS_CXX20 would only be defined inside stdlib headers anyway. I'll add an example.

Comment: Did you install an update to Visual C++ through the installer?

Comment: It's not `#ifdef _HAS_CXX20`.  it's **`#if _HAS_CXX20`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine for me, _HAS_CXX20 is properly set. and `is_constant_evaluated` works as intended.

```
std::cout << _HAS_CXX20;
```

outputs `1`.

My implementation:

```cpp
#if _HAS_CXX20
// FUNCTION is_constant_evaluated
_NODISCARD constexpr bool is_constant_evaluated() noexcept {
    return __builtin_is_constant_evaluated();
}
#endif // _HAS_CXX20
```

The problem appears to be that you are using `#ifdef` instead of `#if`.

Comment: Thanks. That's a related but different issue I think. MS *have* implemented is_constant_evaluated, it just seems that there's no straightforward way to stop the preprocessor from throwing it away.

Comment: see lines 1787-1792 of <type_traits> for their implementation of is_constant_evaluated

Comment: fwiw the implementation just wraps a call to __builtin_is_constant_evaluated() - if I use that directly, it works - suggesting that at least that intrinsic can be used in constexpr context, as you'd hope ;)

Comment: @DanGroom Just to be sure, my implementation `#if _HAS_CXX20
// FUNCTION is_constant_evaluated
_NODISCARD constexpr bool is_constant_evaluated() noexcept {
    return __builtin_is_constant_evaluated();
}
#endif // _HAS_CXX20`

Comment: @DanGroom, anyway, I can't reproduce your errors, it works fine for me, _HAS_CXX20 is properly set. and `is_constant_evaluated` works fine.

Comment: Interesting! What version of MSVC are you using?

Comment: and are you passing /std:c++latest?

Comment: @DanGroom yes I am.

Comment: MSVC 16.6.5? or another version? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes, that's my version

Comment: @DanGroom Compiler Version 19.26.28806, if that helps, probably not.

Comment: @DanGroom, the nuclear option would be to reinstall the program. I can't see what can be wrong.

Comment: @DanGroom, I posted details of my setup in the answer, maybe you can spot the difference, let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @DanGroom, if `__builtin_is_constant_evaluated()` works, you can just define _HAS_CXX20 as 1.

Comment: I think I must have been changing the std setting for one build config and building using another, because when I make sure the UI is setting properties for all configurations and all platforms, it works as you describe. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: You didn't point out OP's usage mistake for the `_HAS_CXX20` macro.   You included the correct usage in your code, but the fact that you missed OP's mistake is why you can't reproduce OP's error.

Comment: Well spotted @Spencer, I missed that.